# Tailwind file changes not getting reflected on the page when the file is reponed

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

whenever i open the project again the file tailwind properties are not getting reuilded and if i add new properties like text-color that too not refelected. Any solution?

Need the project to run and take new properites whenever i open the file again.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same challenges on my project too but l noticed that l had skipped some of the essential steps on the installation of Tailwindcss.
Try to check if you have installed tailwindcss in your project correctly on https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation and check this one if your project uses react https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app@NIRANJAN SR.